# Can i reset multiple forms by calling reset once in redux form

Tags: redux, reset, redux-form

can i reset multiple form by dispatching the reset function once?
When an action is dispatched i want to reset three forms? Can i invoke the reset function like this? `reset('form12', 'form132', 'form2332')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided [action-creator](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-reset-form-string-code-) doesn't support multiple forms at once, but you could create your own reusable thunk:

```
const reset = (...forms) => dispatch => {
    forms.forEach(form => dispatch(reset(form));
}
```